# Is it possible to include external dlls in a silverlight project, that weren't built for silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dll, silverlight-3.0

We're trying to work out a deployment strategy for an internal tool that we're creating. It's a control that uses a set of 3rd party libraries to communication with a specific type of server. So I have a class library built that uses these libraries.

I was looking to deploy a silverlight application that uses our library, which in turn uses a set of 3rd party libraries. When trying to reference the 3rd party libraries, I get the "library can not be referenced because it was not built as a silverlight library".

The type of project I'm trying to build is a silverlight application - not a dll library or anything else. Is it possible to create a silverlight application using libraries created outside of silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Silverlight cannot load dlls compiled using Desktop or .Net Compact Framework versions of the .Net Runtime.